# Input and output redirection in shell

Tags: c, shell, io-redirection

I am trying to implement input and output redirection is C. I read all of the answers to this question, but it does not work! It goes to the last if (`execvp`).

I want something like this:

output redirection: `ls -al > output.txt`

input redirection: `sort < input.txt`

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
int io_redirection(char * args[], char* inputFile, char* outputFile, int option){

    int err = -1;

    int fileDescriptor = -1; // between 0 and 19
    pid_t pid = -10;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid==-1){
        printf("Child process could not be created\n");
        return;
    }
    if(pid==0){
        // Option 0: output redirection
        if (option == 0){
            // I also tried fileDescriptor = creat(outputFile, 0644);
            fileDescriptor = open(outputFile, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0600); 
            dup2(fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO); 
            close(fileDescriptor);


        }
         else if (option == 1){
            // Option 1: input redirection

            fileDescriptor = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY, 0600);  
            dup2(fileDescriptor, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fileDescriptor);

        }



        if (execvp(args[0],args)==err){
            printf("err");
            kill(getpid(),SIGTERM);
        }        
    }
    waitpid(pid,NULL,0);
}
```

for the output redirection `args` contains `ls` and `-al`. And for the input one it contains `sort`.

Comment: You don't need to test the return value from `execvp()` — if it returns, it failed; if it succeeds, it doesn't return.  You don't seem to have allowed for `sort < input.txt > output.txt` — both input and output redirection on a single command.

Comment: Without [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to say what state `args` is in? Have the elements holding `'<'` or `'>'` and the filenames already been removed so that only additional arguments remain?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is not about that, I used this approach multiple times in my code(for example in `pipe`, and it didn't cause any problem), besides I tried to remove the testing of its return, but in that way, it does not go out of the loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin For this example `ls -al > output.txt`: args contain `ls` and `-al`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execvp requires a NULL as the last paramter. I am guessing your command synthesis ignores that, the rest works as intended.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>


void print_child_status (int status) {
  if (WIFEXITED (status)) {
    fprintf (stdout, "Child exited with status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS (status));
  } else if (WIFSTOPPED (status)) {
    fprintf (stdout, "Child stopped by signal %d (%s)\n", WSTOPSIG (status), strsignal (WSTOPSIG (status)));
  } else if (WIFSIGNALED (status)) {
    fprintf (stdout, "Child killed by signal %d (%s)\n", WTERMSIG (status), strsignal (WTERMSIG (status)));
  } else {
    fprintf (stdout, "Unknown child status\n");
  }
}

int io_redirection(char * args[], char* inputFile, char* outputFile, int option){

    int err = -1;

    int fileDescriptor = -1; // between 0 and 19
    pid_t pid = -10;
    pid = fork();

    if(pid==-1){
        printf("Child process could not be created\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
        // Option 0: output redirection
        if (option == 0){
            // I also tried fileDescriptor = creat(outputFile, 0644);
            fileDescriptor = open(outputFile, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0600); 
            dup2(fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO); 
            close(fileDescriptor);


        }
         else if (option == 1) {
            // Option 1: input redirection
            fileDescriptor = open(inputFile, O_RDONLY);
             printf("Input redirection %d\n", fileDescriptor);
            dup2(fileDescriptor, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fileDescriptor);

        }
        err = execvp(args[0], args);

        if (err){
            printf("err %d\n", err);
        }
        return err;
    } else {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status,0);
        print_child_status(status);
    }
    return 0;

}

int main() {
    char * args[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
    io_redirection(args, NULL, "out.txt", 0);
    char * args1[] = {"grep", "main", NULL};
    io_redirection(args1, "./test.c", NULL, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But still it does not work for the input redirection

Comment: It works for me, check the status of open(), you could be referring a file that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your test wrong, I use the following `code` test is right.

```
int main() {
  char* argv[] = {"ls", "-al", NULL};
  io_redirection(argv, NULL, "test", 0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it was my mistake, I fixed that. It works for output redirection, but it does not for the input one

Comment: Make sure the input file exists and has sufficient permissions to open it , and how do you test it? @Setareh